# Can't get clicked row's data from xtragridview

Tags: c#, linq, gridview, devexpress, row

```
private void gridControl1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int rowHandle = gridView1.FocusedRowHandle;
        object myColumnValue = gridView1.GetRowCellValue(rowHandle, "PName Lastname");

    }
```

I'm using dbml as datasource, xtragridview as gridview. 
My problem is I can't see colums in gridview's run designer's columns tab. So, when I want to use column name in code I'm writing column names that are showing on gridview on runtime. But they seem to be not true. I'm not familiar with using LINQ.
GetDataRow() GetRow() etc returns null. How do I get clicked/focused row's data from gridview?

Answer (score 1):

*First: DevExpress has really superb Help, they usually answer such questions fast.*

Anyway, here how it works:

First don't use the Click function ,because it triggers on any Click onto the Component,
but you want to get only the Click onto a Cell to get the Value (`RowClick` or `RowCellClick`).

In the Example bellow i actually wait for a double click (e.Clicks == 2)

**Notice "DataEntry" is a Type which is used when binding to the DataSource**

In my Example it was something like this `gridControlData.DataSource = source`
Where source was of type `List<DataEntry>`.

If you not sure what type is used, use an "Object" instead and then use `Debug.Print(obj.GetType());`

Once you have your Object (it might be a DataRow in your case) ,then you can use that object accordingly.

```
private void gridViewData_RowClick(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.RowClickEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Clicks == 2)
    {
        DataEntry entry = gridViewData.GetRow(e.RowHandle) as DataEntry;

        if (entry != null)
        {

            Debug.Print(entry.Number);
        }
    }
}
```

Addiditional note: the Captions (Name of the Columns) is automatically changed by DevExpress,so for example a column with Fieldname of "Number_Children" might show up as "Number Children" automatically.